# Is softicle.com legit?

Tags: download, iso-image, website, license, product-key

I was recently trying to re-install a Windows 8 machine, when I discovered that no installation media was provided with my machine.

I then discovered this website, softicle.com. Here you can download most Microsoft product ISOs, their SHA1 hash matches the official ones from Microsoft. They even host the ISOs on Google Drive.

Is this site legit? I am completely unable to find any mentioning or discussion about it when searching the Internet.

Also they sell product licenses, at fairly cheap prices, is there some way I can verify that the product licenses are real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows ISOs can be legally downloaded in many places. See related questions:

- [Where can I download Windows 8 legally, from Microsoft?](https://superuser.com/q/493766/194694)
- [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/q/78761/194694)
- [Where can I download windows vista legally?](https://superuser.com/q/794941/194694)

Windows disc itself has no value. What you pay for is a **license**, ie. right to use the software and **license key** which comes with Windows on a sticker. You have to enter that key in Windows installer in order to use it longer than 30 days.

Don't trust downloaded ISOs, though, unless they are official Microsoft downloads. Always verify SHA1 and other hashes of **actual downloaded files**. It's best to use official, Microsoft-approved download channels (see questions linked above for details).

Comment: This was also what I thought, but it seems so convoluted to find isos from Microsoft. Do you know how I can verify that the product licenses they sell are legit?

Comment: I think only Microsoft can verify it.