# Will Windows Vista COA Keys work as a valid product key for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a Windows Vista Home Premium Laptop with a genuine license key. I was wondering if that key would be accepted as a valid key for Windows 10 if I downloaded the ISO from Microsoft and tried to install it.

Thanks.

PS: The Vista copy I have currently is loaded with bloatware. If I downloaded a Windows Vista Home Premium ISO (say, torrent) and tried to install it, would this key work?

Comment: Likely not, as Vista installations are not eligible for a free upgrade to Windows 10. You'll need to purchase a new Windows 10 license, and you'll need to clean install ("keep nothing"). If you have a valid Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 key, you would be able to upgrade.

Comment: **Don't** download any Windows ISOs from anywhere other than Microsoft or your computer vendor's official channels. You may luck out, but odds are against you if you do that the copy you get will have malware or other elements you do not want installed on your PC.

Comment: Here are some related questions.  [Download Windows Vista Home Premium to use with my own key?](http://superuser.com/questions/224078/download-windows-vista-home-premium-to-use-with-my-own-key?rq=1) and [Where can I download windows vista legally?](http://superuser.com/questions/794941/where-can-i-download-windows-vista-legally?rq=1)  The Windows 10 installer only accepts Windows 10 keys

Comment: Very old topic I know, but for the sake of correctness I'll post anyway. I have installed Windows 10 many times with Vista and Win 7 keys. Microsoft even said it would work when they said you can clean install your free Win10 upgrade.

Comment: @djgandy I know you didn't use a Windows Vista license key to activate a Windows 10 installation.

Answer (score -3):

> I have a Windows Vista Home Premium Laptop with a genuine license key.
>   I was wondering if that key would be accepted as a valid key for
>   Windows 10 if I downloaded the ISO from Microsoft and tried to install
>   it.

No.

What makes you think it would?

> If I downloaded a Windows Vista Home Premium ISO (say, torrent) and
>   tried to install it, would this key work?

Yes.

What makes you think it wouldn't?

Comment: [Please be nice.](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: _"What makes you think it would?"_ - well, for example the fact that Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 keys would work.